# <b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: _Get in

Tags: php, html, html5, get, редирект

Добрый день. 
Пытаюсь настроить проброс меток через преленд. Сделал пхп файл с содержимым:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=https://redirect.appmetrica.yandex.com/serve/674048837559559848?c=MyDSP&click_id=<?=$_Get['click']?>&source_id=<?=$_Get['pub']?>&MDapp_id=<?=$_Get['utm_content']?>&MDapp_name=<?=$_Get['name']?>&MDsite_id={<?=$_Get['utm_term']?>&MDappstore_url=<?=$_Get['MDappstore']?>&MDdev_model=<?=$_Get['MDdev']?>&MDrefferer=<?=$_Get['MDrefferer']?>&MDpage_url=<?=$_Get['MDpage']?>&MDtimestamp=<?=$_Get['MDtimestamp']?>&MDdomain=<?=$_Get['MDdomain']?>&MDuser_id=<?=$_Get['MDuser']?>&MD_GAID=<?=$_Get['GAID']?>&MDexchange=<?=$_Get['utm_source']?>&MDcreative_id=<?=$_Get['MDcreative']?>&MDcampaign_id=<?=$_Get['MDcampaign']?>">
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

При нажатии по кнопке перехода выдаёт белый экран, при просмотре кода видно замечание -

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&source_id=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDapp_id=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDapp_name=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDsite_id={<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDappstore_url=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDdev_model=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDrefferer=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDpage_url=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDtimestamp=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDdomain=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDuser_id=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MD_GAID=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDexchange=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDcreative_id=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&MDcampaign_id=<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _Get in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
```

Подскажите, что я забыл добавить в код?

Comment: Добрый день. В ошибке же всё сказано. Не инициализирована переменная.

Comment: Понимаю, что вопрос простой, но как её инициализировать? Пробовал переходить на сайт по ссылке с параметрами - utm_source=1&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1&utm_content=1&utm_term=1&click=1&name=1, не помогает

Comment: Можно как-то прописать, что бы в случаи пустой переменно происходил редирект без подстановки?

Comment: if(!empty($_GET)){ }

Comment: Эту переменную вставлять в ссылку или отдельно?

Comment: Сначала сформируйте переменные - потом подставляйте в запрос.

Answer (score 3):

Нет суперглобального массива `$_Get`. Есть суперглобальный массив `$_GET`.

Comment: Исправил на $_GET, всё тот же -
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: click in <b>/var/www/u0412671/data/www/yandex-dzen.site/one.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
&source_id=<br />

Comment: Не "всё тот же", а другая ошибка. Вы не передаёте get-параметр 'click'. Прежде чем Использовать параметр, убедитесь в его существовании с помощью `isset`,  `null coalesce` оператор (`??`) или `empty`

Comment: Спасибо! Заметил разницу. 
Как правильно использовать операторы isset, null coalesce, (??) в моём случаи, когда в одну ссылку вставлено большое количество переменных?

Comment: `...&click_id=<?=($_GET['click'] ?? '')?>` - это для проверки параметра `click`, если он не задан или `null`, то присвоится пустая строка (работает только начиная с php 7.0). Такую проверку сделать для каждого параметра. Или заранее каждый параметр присвоить переменным, и в url вставлять уже проверенные переменные

Comment: Отлично, ошибки пропали! Правда редирект не происходит. Страница белая, при просмотре кода видно следующее: 

<meta https-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=https:// yandex.com/serve/674048837559559848?c=MyDSP&click_id=&source_id=&MDapp_id=&MDapp_name=&MDsite_id=&MDappstore_url=&MDdev_model=&MDrefferer=&MDpage_url=&MDtimestamp=&MDdomain=&MDuser_id=&MD_GAID=&MDexchange=&MDcreative_id=&MDcampaign_id=">

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос

Comment: Интересно. А с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Вставьте лучше вместо всего html кода такой код: `<?php header('Location: ваш урл');
exit;

Comment: Прописал 
<?php 
header('Location: https:// yandex.com/serve/674048837559559848?c=MyDSP&click_id=<?=($_GET['click'] ?? '')?>&source_id=<?=($_GET['pub'] ?? '')?>&MDapp_id=<?=($_GET['utm_content'] ?? '')?>&MDapp_name=<?=($_GET['name'] ?? '')?>&MDsite_id=<?=($_GET['utm_term'] ?? '')?>&MDappstore_url=<?=($_GET['MDappstore'] ?? '')?>&MDdev_model=<?=($_GET['MDdev'] ?? '')?>&MDrefferer=<?=($_GET['MDrefferer'] ?? '')?>&MDpage_url=<?=($_GET['MDpage'] ?? '')?>'); exit;
?>`

Выдаёт 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'click' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in

Comment: Я сейчас проверил, эта ошибка возникает если я добавляю к ссылке &click_id=<?=($_GET['click'] ?? '')?>

Comment: Перед тем, как вставлять урл, сформируйте его полностью в отдельную переменную

Comment: Как это сделать?